# How should you type an enumerable property in .NET Core configuration when using options?

Tags: c#, .net-core, fxcop

I'm trying to work out the best way of using enumerable properties in an options object that's populated through appsettings.json configuration.

I have an example object below that I'll be configuring from an appsettings.json file that looks like this:

```cs
public class MyOptions
{
    public ICollection<string> ListOne { get; set; } = Array.Empty<string>();

    public string[] ListTwo { get; set; } = Array.Empty<string>();

    public ICollection<string> ListThree { get; } = Array.Empty<string>();
}
```

```
{
    "MyOptions": {
        "ListOne": [ "one", "two", "three" ],
        "ListTwo": [ "one", "two", "three" ],
        "ListThree": [ "one", "two", "three" ]
    }
}
```

The problem here is that when using FxCop analysers a warning is raised against ListOne: `CA2227: Collection properties should be read only`.
And a different one against ListTwo: `CA1819: Properties should not return arrays`.
And if you the setter from ListOne like done in ListThree to fix the warning then the configuration isn't read in at all because it needs a setter.

So my question is really, well if you can't any of that, how do you populate an enumerable property without any warnings?